# Why Peroxydisulphuric Acid is also called as Marshall's Acid and Peroxymonosulphuric Acid as Caro's Acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, nomenclature

I recently come across the oxaacids of Sulphur and got to know to Acids, $\ce{H2S2O8}$ and $\ce{H2SO5}$ as Marshall's Acid and Caro's Acid respectively, but I am just eager to know why they are named respectively so.

I tried searching in Google and couldn't found any relevant information regarding the same.

Comment: It is named after respective chemists who discovered it.

Comment: @NilayGhosh, It is not necessary that they "discovered" it. You will have to check the original papers from 1890s! In the very first line he says that Bertholet described it initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are curious about word or name origins like I am, get hold of two books:

1. Elsevier's Dictionary of Chemoetymology: The Whies and Whences of Chemical Nomenclature and Terminology
2. Alex Nikon's Organic Chemistry The Name Game.

In older times, it was pretty common to name a compound after a person who described the preparation or because nobody knew the structure. Nothing unusual about it. Here is the entry:

Caro’s acid:$\ce{H2SO5}$, named for the German chemist Heinrich Caro (1834-1910)

Marshall’s acid: $\ce{H2S2O8}$, named for the 19th century Scottish chemist Hugh Marshall